# How to execute a c file on the command line

Tags: c, command-line

I am very new to C programming, and have written this C program that takes in an input N, and gives a list of all the numbers up to N that are exactly divisible by 7. The program I have written is as follows;

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c,n,k;
    int i=0;
    int AnswerList [1000];
    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (c=1;c<=n;c++){
        if(c%7==0){
            AnswerList[i]=c;
            i++;
        }

    }
    for (k=0;k<=i;k++){
       printf("%d\n", AnswerList[k]);

    }       
    return 0;
}
```

I need my program to run such that if N equals 27, I should be able to type into the command line

```
./byseven 27
```

In other words, I need to write code that bypasses the printf line I think. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look into argc, argv  : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-1/onyourown/C.argv.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, is there a better way to set up the array other than arbitrarily declaring its size to be 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [command-line arguments](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html). A simple example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s N\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
     }

     int N = atoi(argv[1]); // atoi is used to convert a string to an int
     // your code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, is there a better way to set up the array other than arbitrarily declaring its size to be 1000?

Comment: If you just want to print the number, you don't need to store them inside an array. Instead directly print them. If you need to store them, your now that you will have at most `N/7` numbers, so you can use dynamic allocation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) to reserve the exact amount of memory you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `int main(int argc, char** argv)` definition. Then `argc` will be number of your params (first param is always the name of your program), and `argv` is array of string which contains that params. And `scanf` function is not needed therefore.

Answer (score -2):

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

It will compile and produced an exectuable file called hello. To run program type:

```
./hello
```

Comment: -1: OP is not asking how to compile and run - he is asking how to pass command line arguments

Comment: sorry i can't see after the titled question.